# How to make a forked dependency in package.json run its prepare script during npm install?

Tags: npm, dependencies

I forked [a NPM module](https://github.com/mifi/ical-expander) and modified it in [my fork](https://github.com/haukepribnow/ical-expander). In my fork, the command `gulp` needs to be run to compile the module. Running this command will output the file `ical-expander-dist.js` into the `dist` folder. This file should become part of the fork package.

The adjusted `package.json` in my fork looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "ical-expander",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "ICS / iCal / iCalendar parser / expander",
  "main": "dist/ical-expander-dist.js", // adjusted path
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "gulp" // added script
  },
  // [SNIP] - excluded irrelevant lines
  "files": [
    "dist/ical-expander-dist.js" // adjusted path
  ]
}
```

---

Now I want to make my fork a dependency of another project.

```
{
  "name": "otherproject",
  "title": "Other Project",
  // [SNIP] - excluded irrelevant lines
  "dependencies": {
    "ical-expander": "github:haukepribnow/ical-expander"
  }
  // [SNIP] - excluded irrelevant lines
}
```

After executing `npm install` in `otherproject`'s root folder, the path `./node_modules/ical-expander` will contain the files `LICENSE`, `README.md` and `package.json`. It will however not contain `dist/ical-expander-dist.js`.

It looks like the `prepare` script of my ical-expander fork is not being run during `npm install` in `otherproject`.

---

So my question boils down to: How can I make sure that preparation scripts for compiling my fork are being run when executing `npm install` in a project that has my fork as one of its dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's very simple: Make sure to use `npm` version 5.0.0 or higher.

According to [the npm changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/dcc4273cadebe70f853e6d948a425978bc42e045/CHANGELOG.md#feature-summary), `npm install` will run dependencies' `prepare` scripts correctly from 5.0.0 on.